# Playframework generateSignedToken vs generateToken

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

i have used both methods generateSignedToken and generateToken but i don't fully understand the difference between both (besides the string length)...which one is better to generate a nonce token?

btw i read the api description for both methods but i find it confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generateSignedToken` method uses the `signToken` method on a token generated by `generateToken` (as you can see in the [source on github](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/Crypto.scala)). The documentation says about the signToken method ([Documentation of play.libs.Crypto](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/api/java/play/libs/Crypto.html#signToken%28java.lang.String%29)):

> Sign a token. This produces a new token, that has this token signed with a nonce. This primarily exists to defeat the BREACH vulnerability, as it allows the token to effectively be random per request, without actually changing the value.

[Wikipedia on the BREACH vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH_%28security_exploit%29)

Comment: I haven't been working a lot with sign tokens in play 2.0 and I'm not an security expert (DISCLAIMER END), but I think it depends on how you validate you tokens. If you pass a token to the client, you also have to keep it on the server somewhere (Cache, DB...). If you have control over that validation process you are able to invalidate the tokens by deleting them.

Comment: thank you Tilman, you have been very helpful, i'll try to validate with Cache expiration and see how it works. have a nice day!

Comment: Ok, storing the token in the Cache or DB is probably not the way to go. Maybe take a look at this module: https://github.com/orefalo/play2-authenticitytoken